# Invalid Transmission rate error

Tags: c++, omnet++

For my project, I need to use channel which has different data rate values, such has 50Mbps, 60Mbps, 80Mbps, 100Mbps, 200Mbps, 300Mbps.
 Firstly, I changed the datarate parameter in .NED file

```
network OpenflowScenario
{
    @display("bgb=570,393");
    types:
        channel ethline extends DatarateChannel
        {
            delay = 50ns;
            datarate = 200Mbps;
        }
```

Then,I also tried to change the Etherlink.ned file (Inet>src>inet>node>ethernet>Etherlink)and I added new channel classes like Eth50, Eth60, Eth80.... 
 However, I got error, when I tried to run it.. How can i fix it?
[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethernet can only use datarates defined by standard (i.e. 10 Mbit/s, 100 Mbit/s, 1000 Mbit/s, etc.). Therefore, one cannot assign other datarate to an Etherent link.

Comment: Is there any channel type I can use instead of ethernet link?

Comment: Yes, you can use PPP link.